# Error when installing package.json after Python

Tags: python, npm

I'm trying to run `npm install` as *root* for my project. The first time, it said that the Python path was incorrect.

I reinstalled Python to a newer version, but when I run `npm install`, it doesn't work. I'm getting errors and I don't know what to do.

```
6540 verbose npm  v8.1.2
6541 error code 1
6542 error path C:\wamp\www\xxxxxx\node_modules\node-sass
6543 error command failed
6544 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
6545 error Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\wamp\www\xxxxxx\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
6546 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
6546 error gyp verb cli [
6546 error gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
6546 error gyp verb cli   'C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxxx\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
6546 error gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
6546 error gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
6546 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
6546 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
6546 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
6546 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
6546 error gyp verb cli ]
6546 error gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
6546 error gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
6546 error gyp verb command rebuild []
6546 error gyp verb command clean []
6546 error gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
6546 error gyp verb command configure []
6546 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "C:\Python311\python.exe" in the PATH
6546 error gyp verb `which` succeeded C:\Python311\python.exe C:\Python311\python.exe
6546 error gyp ERR! configure error
6546 error gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python311\python.exe -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
6546 error gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
6546 error gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
6546 error gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
6546 error gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
6546 error gyp ERR! stack
6546 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
6546 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
6546 error gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
6546 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
6546 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
6546 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxxx\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
6546 error gyp ERR! cwd C:\wamp\www\xxxxxx\node_modules\node-sass
6546 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
6546 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
6546 error gyp ERR! not ok
6546 error Build failed with error code: 1
6547 verbose exit 1
```

***Update***:

I followed [the answer from user staocube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76656999/error-when-installing-package-json-after-python/76657244#76657244), but I still got the error when I tried to install npm install.

I don’t understand what’s wrong.

```
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path C:\wamp\www\xxxxx\node_modules\node-sass
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
    npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\wamp\www\xxxxx\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxx\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
    npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
    npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
    npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "C:\Python27\python.exe" in the PATH
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import sys; print "2.7.2
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
    npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.13.1
    npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.13.1' ]
    npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.13.1"
    npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.13.1
    npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
    npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
    npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
    npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
    npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
    npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.13.1
    npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\wamp\www\xxxxx\node_modules\node-sass\build
    npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\wamp\www\xxxxx\node_modules\node-sass\build
    npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041
    npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
    npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base
    npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Using this installation with Windows 10 SDK
    npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 using installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
    npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: C:\wamp\www\xxxxx\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
    npm ERR! (node:15060) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
    npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
    npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\wamp\www\xxxxx\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
    npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\wamp\www\xxxxx\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
    npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxx\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxx\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxx\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\nikla\\.node-gyp\\16.13.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\nikla\\.node-gyp\\16.13.1',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxx\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\nikla\\.node-gyp\\16.13.1\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxx\\node_modules\\node-sass',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxx\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]

npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\nikla\.node-gyp\16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
npm ERR! gyp verb using MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxx\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\wamp\www\xxxxx\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
npm ERR! gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 7
```

Comment: Looks like the package depends on Python 2.

Comment: try bumping node-gyp to the latest version